# How do I control how many processes run in the background on Android Marshmellow 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, performance, background-process

My tablet has a tendency to run kind of slow, and I think it's because there's too much running in the background.  How do I control how many things get started at one time?

Comment: Do you have root?

Comment: @IrfanLatif No, it isn't jail broken.

Comment: Then you are left with Running Services in Developer Options. But that's not as helpful as rooted device can be.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I found 3 ES File Explorers running in background services!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes ES Explorer is a battery hog sometimes. Use Solid Explorer or MiXplorer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif You mean Memory Hog?

Comment: Yeah. A piece of software consuming one source heavily usually consumes others as well